# How do I get a scrollbar to appear in a Rally cardboard component?

Tags: extjs, containers, rally

Asking and answering my own question thanks to a post on another topic:

I have created a cardboard in a custom Rally app. The list of items within the cardboard is longer than the screen will show, but there is no scroll bar in the window or the container. I've tried adding `autoScroll:true` to first level properties of the cardboard and to both the `storeConfig` and `listConfig` of the cardboard. Nothing works. WTH?

Comment: Thanks for your post.  The layouts and containers can be pretty intricate in Ext.  This will definitely help some folks out!

Comment: Interesting. Please edit and post the solution as an answer instead of an edit.

Comment: Second that, add an answer and mark it as answered. Otherwise people cannot see it was already answered

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from [Anders Martinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1686698/anders-martinson)

You have to add autoScroll:true to the app definition:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    autoScroll: true,
    //...
}
```

Once you do that, you're set.